# More polite/formal way of saying "Y'a intérêt"

Tags: registre-familier

> « Quel magnifique spécimen. »

In response, I’d like to say something along the lines of:

> « Y'a intérêt, vu ce qu'on a dû faire pour l'obtenir. »

... but in the more ***polite/formal*** form. I suppose that "**Y'a intérêt**" is a somewhat casual expression that rougly translates into "**it (had) better be**". How would you express this entire sentence more formally?

Comment: Heureusement ! Vu...

Comment: "Encore heureux" can be used too, and means the same thing that "Heureusement", but has the same politeness than "Y'a intérêt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from Casey James Garland is correct. Here are other possibilities:

"**Encore heureux**, vu ce qu'on a dû faire..." - which is not more formal than "Y'a intérêt".

"**C'est bien le moins**, vu ce qu'on a dû faire..." - formal/polite.

Comment: (+1) “C'est bien le moins” seems closest to “Y a intérêt”, which expresses a bit more than just lucking out, i.e. you are talking about something you feel you are entitled or would be angry at not getting…

Answer (score 5):

Considering that "It had better be" doesn't come off as very formal or polite in English, I'm not sure what you're looking for...

These may not be much more formal, but here are some other options:

« **Heureusement**, **étant donné** ce qu'on a dû faire pour l'obtenir. »

« **J'espère bien**, vu ce qu'on ... »

« **Tant mieux**, vu ce qu'on ... »

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, the word "heureusement" means "fortunately". Does "heureusement" also mean "it better be"?

Comment: "Heureusement" can also mean "thankfully," "luckily," or in the right context, "it's a good thing (that)..."

I think that this is a good example of where it could fall under the latter scenario, especially since you wanted it to sound a little more polite/formal.

Comment: I think “Heureusement” or “Tant mieux” could it but have slightly different undertones. Among those three, “J'espère bien” is closest to “Y a intérêt”.